# Correct long / lat referencing typo in vector layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gvsig

[This layer](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/data/web_data/gasflares_v2/country_vectors_20090618/Flares_Cote_dIvoire_1.tgz) is completely misallinged in terms of the standard WGS84 referencing system. I played around a lot with affine transformations and the like. But I presume it is just a typo in the underlying long/lat (e.g. instead of -655 it should be -6.55).
Is there any way to "retype" long/lat manually in QGIS or gvSIG?

Comment: Didn't affine transformation with scale=0.01 work for you?

Comment: It did! Thanks a lot, somehow I didn't see the obvious solution. But I'm still curious if there is a possibility to manually change long/lat.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this (in gvSIG 2.2):
1. Start editing
2. Use the tool “Move”
3. First point:  with right button you can write the coordinates of the point. You can use the coordinates of one of the nodes[*] (X:-331.89819999999963 Y:617.5137999999997)
4. Second point (with right button): X:-3.3189819999999963 Y:6.175137999999997
As result, gvSIG move all the selected features to the new position/coordinates.

[*] In gvSIG 2.2 you can go to the properties of the table and check the GEOMETRY column. Then, you can view this column in the Table of attributes